# Estimate DC current from phase current in BLDC motor

Tags: motor, power-electronics, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor

I am using a BLDC motor with sinusoidal windings that I drive with FOC. The implementation uses a triple half-bridge and a DRV83 to drive the MOSFETs. I have 3 low-side amplifiers to measure the phase current ***Ia***, ***Ib*** and ***Ic***. The power is given by a DC power supply.

How can I estimate the instantaneous current ***Idc*** drawn from my power supply with my three phase currents ***Ia***, ***Ib*** and ***Ic***?

Comment: I would expect it to be more promising to estimate \$average I_{DC}\$ from *power* than from phase current(s). \$I_{DC}\$ does not need to equal \$\sum I_{phase} \$ where the phase currents are controlled by, effectively, buck converters.

Comment: @greybeard I understand this would help to get a more direct and accurate estimation but I don't have access to Idc on my system

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the phase currents by the cosine of the appropriate angles and summing them up with their respective weights (2/3) will give you an estimation of the DC current drawn from the power supply. Keep in mind that this formula assumes balanced three-phase currents. So, you get:

$$\text{I}_\text{dc}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\left(\text{I}_\text{a}\cos\left(30^\circ\right)+\text{I}_\text{b}\cos\left(150^\circ\right)+\text{I}_\text{c}\cos\left(270^\circ\right)\right)\tag1$$

Which leads to:

$$\text{I}_\text{dc}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\left(\text{I}_\text{a}-\text{I}_\text{b}\right)\tag2$$

Comment: Thanks ! it is a convenient way to compute the DC current. Do you have a link to literature ressource that derives those equations ?

Comment: After a second look, I realize that this equation cannot be true as Idc should always be the same sign but the sign of (Ia - Ib) is fluctuating between negative and positive

Answer (score 0):

*Instantaneous* \$I_{DC}\$ should be the sum of the phase currents
(positive currents from positive supply, negative currents to negative supply potential).
Otherwise, charges would need to accumulate *somewhere*.

Comment: Sum of the phase currents is always equal to 0. Simple Kirchhoff law. So the answer is somewhere else.